# Upgrade Ubuntu Server 11.04 signature error

Tags: server, upgrade, 11.04, release-management

Hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

When i do a do-release-upgrade i get an error about signature.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Err Upgrade tool signature
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err Upgrade tool
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
WARNING:root:file 'oneiric.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You would have to do two sets of upgrades to get to the latest 14.04 LTS. It would be much easier, and with less potential for things to go wrong, to install a new 14.04 release.

Comment: I installed and configured ImageMagick/PHP on this server. I don't want to redo all those settings again. So i prefer to upgrade.